# How to close associated token account using web3js solana tools

Tags: web3js, solana

Is there any way to close the associated account using JS libs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You can use the normal `closeAccount()` function that exists on the `Token` object, if you have one: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e8b7009cc4d8cdd87232ccfc9ce93ab203ada496/token/js/client/token.js#L1109

And here's a test example using that function: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e8b7009cc4d8cdd87232ccfc9ce93ab203ada496/token/js/cli/token-test.js#L480

If you don't, then you'll have to roughly copy the implementation of the first link, creating a `closeAccount` instruction using `createCloseAccountInstruction` and signing it with the owner: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e8b7009cc4d8cdd87232ccfc9ce93ab203ada496/token/js/client/token.js#L1850